# Sequence of functions is uniformly convergent to a function (f). Is sequence of their derivatives converging to a derivative (f') at only one point?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

For each $n \in N$ let the function $f_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable, let the function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable and let $f_n \rightrightarrows f$. Is it possible that the sequence $f'_{n}(x)$ converges to $f'(x)$ for exactly one $x ∈ R$? If it is give an example.

Comment: The usual pathological example of $f_n(x) = n^{-1/2} \cos(nx)$ gives $f_n \rightrightarrows 0$, and I believe that $f_n'(x) = -n^{1/2}\sin(nx)$ converges to 0 only for $x = \in \{k\pi\}$. The fact that we can get a discrete set makes me think one point should be possible (we could also swap out $\cos$ for $\sin$, in which case I think $f_n'$ might not converge to $0$ anywhere.

Comment: I think that it is possible to find such function. However I am not sure if sin or cos is the right choice since we are looking for only one point of convergence.

Comment: I suppose that we can get uniform convergence by taking bounded function and dividing by a function that goes to infinity (like simple a/n).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $f_{n}(x)=n^{-1/2}\cos(n^{3/2}x)$. While $f_{n}(x)$ uniformly converges to $0$, $f_{n}’(x)$ converges to $0$ only when $x=0$.

Comment: And $f_n' (x)$ does not converge to $0$ for every $x = k \pi$?

Comment: But, on the other hand, maybe I could take that function on an interval $x \in [0, 4]$

Comment: @mathbb Note that $f’_{n}(x)=-n\sin(n^{3/2}x)$. For a certain $x = k\pi$, take $n_{m} = 2^{m}$, apparently $-2^{m}\sin(2^{3m/2}k\pi)$ does not converge for $k\not=0$.

Comment: Ohh, you are right, I'm sorry. But why do we need that $n^{3/2}$ inside the cos function? Wouldn't $n$ work just fine? I mean, we could take $f_{n}(x)=n^{-1/2}\cos(n * x)$ and not $f_{n}(x)=n^{-1/2}\cos(n^{3/2}x)$, am I right?

Comment: @mathbb If we take $n$, $f’_{n}(x)$ will converge to $0$ when $x = k\pi$ as you’ve said. We take $n^{3/2}$ such that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $n^{3/2}$ are not integers (which is necessary but not sufficient for $f’_{n}(x)$ to not converge when $x=k\pi$, $k\not=0$)

Comment: Yeah, of course! Now when you explained, I see that. Sometimes I am stupid I guess. Thank you for help!